# Should I use 'find the attached document' or 'find attached the document' ?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

How to say that there is an attachment in the mail??

> Please find the attached document

or

> Please find attached the document

I have seen these both are being used in different places. Which is grammatically correct? What is the correct way to say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Please find the attached document" sounds like the better of the two options to me, although I think the 2nd is technically grammatically okay, it just sounds awful.

I also have a bit of a problem with the word "find", because it implies you need to look for something. In the case of something attached to an email you don't need to *find* it, you know exactly where it is.

In the end, I would personally use the phrase

> Please see the attached document.

Comment: Or "Please *refer to* the attached document."

Comment: To find is broadly used when you attach something to your e-mail as it is attached and you have to find it to open it. It is an idiomatic expression. It doesn't mean you have to look for something.